# How to form a word from another word in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello great programmers in the house..
I am quite new to vb.net
I need help on how to detect if a word can be formed from another word:
here's what i mean...

TextBox1.Text="Nairaland"
TextBox2.Text= ....accepts any input

I want to be able to alert "Found!"
if something like ..."land" or "lad" or "Nail" or "Naaad".... is entered into textbox2

but "Not Found" if something like "Qeen" or "Landd" or 'Mail" is entered.

In a nutshell, I just want to be able to check if the characters in textbox2 are found in textbox1...not minding the sequence but no letter should be entered twice/trice except if it appears twice/trice

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build a [Dictionary(Char, Integer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the character count for each character, in both textboxes.  Then see if any of the characters in the second one aren't in the first or have a count greater than the first.

Comment: any sample on how i can do that please, I am new to vb.net

Comment: The link for dictionary documentation is included in the answer. The links there contain samples.

Comment: i did not understand the documentation..I am new to vb.net

Comment: I just need a sample program to search if the content of textbox2 can be found in textbox1 without minding the other..that is.. if a word can be formed from another word